# .Net 3.5 website causes 404 in asp website

Tags: asp-classic, asp.net-3.5

I have a classic asp website running on Application Pool A.  I have a .Net 3.5 website running on Application Pool B.  When I start up .Net 3.5 website, Classic Asp website throws 404 error.  When I stop .Net 3.5 website, Classic Asp website works as expected.

If I use the web server itself and browse \localhost\Classic Asp website, the above problem does not happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are they both running on port 80 with the same host name binding?  You can't have two different websites running on the same port with the same host name binding.    When you start the 2nd website, the first one will stop.